# Retrofit 2, сохранение ответа

Tags: java, android

Имеется код:

```
public void LoadDataShop(int localityId, String parameters){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        Call<Shops> call = service.getShopsBasket(localityId, parameters);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Shops>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Shops> call, Response<Shops> response) {
                Log.e("Запуск","Запуск");
                ArrayList<Shop> shopsArray = response.body().getShops();//
//                Log.e("Размер",String.valueOf(shopsArray.size()));
//                for(int i = 0; i<shopsArray.size();i++){
//                    shops.add(shopsArray.get(i));
//                }
//                shops.addAll(shopsArray);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Shops> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Ошибка",t.getMessage());
            }
        });        
    }
```

Он загружает список магазинов. Необходимо выполнить похожий метод для загрузки цен и только потом передать в адаптер

Проблема в том что я не могу сохранить результат. Пытался засунуть результат 1 запроса в ArrayList, который объявлен глобально во всем классе, и после выполнения этого метода отобразить элементы. Но его длина составляет 0, хотя приходит 7 объектов.

Судя по логам сначала выдает 0, потом 7, скорее всего из-за того что запрос асинхронный и сообщение срабатывает быстрее чем выполнился запрос.

Comment: Откуда вызывается LoadDataShop - что-то связанное с жизненным циклом?

Comment: Вы, наверное, вызываете запросы следом друг за другом, не дожидаясь загрузки первого. Вызывайте второй запрос из `onResponse` первого после заполнения списка - тогда он гарантированно не будет пустым.

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте больше про `CallBack`. В данном случае у вас происходит задержка. Изначально происходит создание и отображение данных, а после получение. Вам стоит либо в `Activity` создавать `Callback` и работать внутри `onResponce`, либо сделать запрос синхронным (это неправильно, но как вариант для вас) примерно как-то так:

```
try {
    call.execute().body()...
}catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```